# unicode declaration in Python and raw string in comments

Tags: python, unicode

By default my Python files have the following at the top of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

*Which I just noticed doesn't matter because I'm using Python 3 ... (same problem below occurs without this line)*

What I had never considered before is how this interacts with raw strings that are in code or in comments. In particular I had the following as a block comment that when importing the module was causing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 42-43: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

This makes sense given the code (below), but is obviously not what I wanted. Is there an easy way around this problem? Is this defined behavior or some edge case?

```
"""
    #Test Code:
    import adi
    f = adi.read_file(r'C:\Users\RNEL\Desktop\test\test_file.adicht')
"""
```

The `\U` in the code is obviously what's causing the problem, but it is a raw string ... but it is inside of a comment ...

Using Python 3.6.5 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"""` is not a raw string in Python, only a multi-line one. Escape sequences still apply.

Did you mean to use `r"""`?

Comment: ... I never considered using `r"""` because I always think of `"""` as a comment! That's the simple fix I needed, thanks!